# Is EF4 mature enough with MySQL or Oracle?

Tags: web-development, c#, frameworks, entity-framework

Is Entity Framework 4 with MySQL or Oracle mature enough to be used on production level web application?

Can it provide high level of performance, or should we stick with just plain data access with `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer with MySQL is yes, but there are things you should keep in mind:

1. If you are starting a new project, it's a good idea to use EF4, but if you are going to use in an existing project, you should stick with what you are using now;
2. Sometimes you will have difficult to find answers for a few problems you may find, there's not a lot of people using it;
3. The [Net/Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net) improved a lot since a couple of years ago, so don't be scared if you look around and find people saying bad things about it;

I'm using with SQLite and with MySQL and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

As for Oracle, they are working on an official [Entity Framework adapter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html), which they say is expected to release production status at the fourth quarter of 2011.

Answer (score 0):

no it isn't mature enough at all. When someone solves the problem with cross-apply queries being generated, then you can start thinking of checking whether performance issues were resolved too. (ie if EF generates a cross-apply type of query, it simply fails to run on Oracle or MySql, or any non-SqlServer DB for that matter).

Performance: EF4 is supposed to be better, but EF3 created truly awful sql for our legacy schema.

If you want to use an ORM [there are others](http://ormeter.net/) that do not have this limitation and some that perform better.